# Prove that $m^*(A)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Suppose that $A$ is a bounded set and that $\forall I\subset \mathbb R \space m^*(A\cap I)\leq \frac{3}4m^*(I)$ Prove that $m^*(A)=0$.

I have got a proof to this that's very different from my friends but I'm not sure if I've got it right. Appreciate if somebody could check it through for me.

My solution:

$A \subset \mathbb R$ is bounded if $\exists l,h\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $l = \inf A$ and $h = \sup A$.

Note that $\bar{A}$ is closed and bounded. By the Heine-Borel Theorem, $\bar{A}$ is compact. Let $\{I_j\}^\infty_{j=1}$ be an open cover of $\bar{A}$. Then after relabelling, $\{I_j\}^N_{j=1}$ is a finite open cover of $\bar{A}$ with $I_j=(a_j,b_j)$ s.t. $a_1<l<\dots<a_N<\dots<h<b_N$.
So $h-l\leq b_N-a_1 \leq\sum^\infty_{j=1}(b_j-a_j)\leq m^*(\bar{A})\leq m^*(A)$ as $A\subset\bar{A}$. Hence $h-l\leq m^*(A)$ - Equation 1.

Now in particular, take $I=(l-\epsilon,h+\epsilon)$. Then $m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap I)$ as  $A\subset I\space\forall\epsilon>0$.
So $m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap I)\leq\frac{3}4m^*(I)=\frac{3}4(h-l+2\epsilon)$. Take $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ to get $m^*(A)\leq\frac{3}4(h-l)$ - Equation 2.

Putting both equations together, we get $m^*(A)=0$.

Comment: The first line should be $\forall I\subset \mathbb R$?

Comment: You state $m^*(\overline A) \le m^*(A)$ as $A \subset \overline A$.  This isn't true.  In the same paragraph you state $\sum_j (b_j - a_j) \le m^*(\overline A)$.  This inequality too is reversed.  Perhaps you should review the definition of Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: Oh gosh. Thanks for spotting that careless mistake! :)